# Cannot run SenseNet source code

Tags: c#, sql-server, sensenet

If anyone has dealt with Sense/Net before, I have a problem running the source code.
Here is what I've done:

1. Downloaded the source code for Sense/Net.
2. Opened the solution in Visual Studio 2010,
3. Set the website project as default project
4. Created a SQL Alias using SQL Sever Configuration Manager

   ```
   (name:"MySenseNetContentRepositoryDatasource"
    Protocol: Named-Pipes
    Server: USER\SQLEXPRESS)
   ```

but when I build and run a message box pops up saying:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server is not
>   configured correctly. See help for more configuration errors. Running
>   the web page outside of the debugger may provide further information.

So I published the website on IIS and browsed. It gave me the following exception:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

I couldn't connect to the Alias from SQL Server Management Studio, I think this is where the problem lies. If anyone can shed some light on the issue, I would very much appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run SenseNet in the VS debugger. Here's how you can run it and debug it if needed.

Once you've built the project, open IIS and create a website by pointing to the website root location. If you have the complete SenseNet source this root location would be the "Source\SenseNet\Website" folder. Once your start the website you can use the debugger in Visual Studio to "Attach to Process", and the process will be "w3wp". You may need to click the "Show all processes" checkbox to see it. For more information see the [SenseNet wiki](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Main_Page).

You should be able to connect to the SQL Server alias from SSMS. If you cannot and don't want to use the alias, you can just edit the connection string in the website `web.config` file to point to the database as shown below:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SnCrMsSql" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=SenseNetContentRepository;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```